# A basic question on limit

Tags: limits, continuity, random-variables

Why for a continuous random variable $X$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ in $[c, c+\delta]$ the following is true:

$$P(c < X \leq x) < \epsilon$$ for any given $\epsilon > 0$.

I can understand it intuitively, but not able to prove how to find that $\delta$.

Comment: any solution insight ??

Comment: Any beginning of hint about what you tried?